# Drop Privilege Issue

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql-5.7

We are using mysql 5.7.22 and I have created a user with drop privilege because this user using temp tables and temp tables needs drop privilege if table already exist. Due to this privilege, user can drop table or any other object. I want user can't able to execute drop table command from client side. Is there any work-around ?

Comment: Wh do you not have different users for that, so depending who's connecting it has privileges or not.

Comment: Dropping temporary tables is never required. Of course, if you use unique names of temporary tables in each place where it is needed. If this is not the case, then put your code in order and develop a system for naming temporary tables so that the same name never occurs in two different sections of code.

Comment: Or are you mixed up on terminology?